# sync local mongodb to and from remote mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, data-synchronization

I have application developed in react (front end application), nodejs/expressjs (rest api) and mongodb.

One copy of application (frontend, rest api, mondogb) running on local which save data in local mongodb and another copy of app running on cloud which save data in cloud mongodb (mongodb atlas).

I want to keep local and remote mongodb in sync, so any new changes in local will be pushed to remote and new changes in remote will be pulled to local.

So, may be a button or background running jobs which would trigger sync process.

What would you suggest best approach/staggery for data synchronization?

Comment: How did you manage to sync this.